# Which node binary management is more popular: nave or n?

Tags: node.js

I am interested in comparing the two binary managers, **nave** and **n**.

One uses **subshell** approach, another is straightforward and has simple syntax.

- Both projects have reputed developers behind them. However, in a production environment is there any feature that really outperforms the other?
- Which one is more PaaS friendly?